# modify the squared sum [ceres-solver]

Tags: c++, ceres-solver

I am trying to modify the default behavior of ceres which is computing the squared sum of residuals as cost function. I want it to compute only a sum ( the residuals are already computed in a manner that they can only be positive)

according to the documentation I should use [ConditionedCostFunction](http://ceres-solver.org/modeling.html#ConditionedCostFunction)

this is what I have done:
I define the conditioner that takes 1 residuals and 1 parameter

```
struct Conditioners : ceres::CostFunction
{
public:
    Conditioners()
    {
        set_num_residuals(1);
        mutable_parameter_block_sizes()->push_back(1);
    }

    ~Conditioners()
    {}

    template<typename T>
    T operator() (T x)
    {
        return T(x * x);
    }

    bool Evaluate(double const* const* parameters, double* residuals, double** jacobians) const
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

I put conditioners inside a vector

```
std::vector<ceres::CostFunction*> conditioners;

for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    conditioners.push_back(new Conditioners());

ceres::ConditionedCostFunction* ccf =
              new ceres::ConditionedCostFunction(cost_function, conditioners, ceres::TAKE_OWNERSHIP);

problem.AddResidualBlock(ccf, NULL, &x);
```

it compiles and everything. But it does not solve the problem. it does not even start. it says :

```
Ceres Solver Report: Iterations: 0, Initial cost: 4.512500e+01, Final cost: 4.512500e+01, Termination: CONVERGENCE
x : 0.5 -> 0.5
```

instead of :

```
iter      cost      cost_change  |gradient|   |step|    tr_ratio  tr_radius  ls_iter  iter_time  total_time
   0  4.512500e+01    0.00e+00    9.50e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00  1.00e+04       0    2.99e-04    1.04e-03
   1  4.511598e-07    4.51e+01    9.50e-04   9.50e+00   1.00e+00  3.00e+04       1    3.84e-04    9.72e-03
   2  5.012552e-16    4.51e-07    3.17e-08   9.50e-04   1.00e+00  9.00e+04       1    2.98e-05    9.92e-03
Ceres Solver Report: Iterations: 2, Initial cost: 4.512500e+01, Final cost: 5.012552e-16, Termination: CONVERGENCE
x : 0.5 -> 10
```

(if you want to try it yourself, this example modifies the [helloword example](http://ceres-solver.org/tutorial.html#hello-world))
Do you have any direction on what went wrong ?? (ceres report was not more specific)

Comment: I don't know the ceres framework you're using... But why does you evaluate function always return true, and does nothing else? seems like it could be the source of your problem...

Comment: it was actually. In the documentation they explain that the Conditioner function is used as if my_f(x). so I thought I only needed to implement the operator() but I actually needed to re implement the Evaluate fonction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, which is :

```
struct Conditioners : ceres::CostFunction
{
public:
Conditioners()
{
    set_num_residuals(1);
    mutable_parameter_block_sizes()->push_back(1);
}

~Conditioners()
{}

template<typename T>
T operator() (T x)
{
    return T(x * x);
}

bool Evaluate(double const* const* parameters, double* residuals, double** jacobians) const
{
    residuals[0] = parameters[0][0] * parameters[0][0]

    if (jacobians)
         jacobians[0][0] = 2.0 * parameters[0][0]

    return true;
}
};
```

My error was to thought I only had to re implement the () operator and that ceres will found out automatically the jacobian. It doesnot.